# Is there a major mode for dbt

Tags: major-mode

I'm trying to use [dbt](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/introduction) in emacs, and I'm hoping that there is a mode for this that will combine the jinja and sql parts in an intelligent way...

I quick google search didn't find anything, so the answer may be "it doesn't exist"...

Comment: If the answer is "it doesn't exist, so you should make one!" ... If I find the time I guess...

Comment: I'm in the same situation. I use https://github.com/tconbeer/sqlfmt as a command line code linter, but it would be nice to have it integrated with emacs or get some reasonable mode that takes care of indentation.

Answer (score 0):

[This one](https://github.com/CyberShadow/dbt-mode) based on Polymode works pretty well.

I modified it to make jinja code stand out a bit more by adding the following to the first innermode:

```
  :adjust-face 10
  :head-adjust-face 10
  :tail-adjust-face 10
```